# Finding PHP scripts that require register_globals

Tags: php, register-globals

I have inherited a web server filled with code that requires `register_globals` to be on.  Most of it is custom code written by random people who have come and gone over the years.  I have fixed the majority of it in scripts that I know about, but my problem is with finding the ones I don't know about.

I am considering writing an application to scan through every directory on the web server to identify PHP scripts that require `register_globals`.  Is there a good strategy for doing this?

One method I have considered involves somehow forcing PHP to report all errors, executing scripts, and checking for undefined variable notices.  I could build an application that reads the `STDERR` stream for this.

Are there any better methods you can think of?

Comment: +1 for not simply using `extract()` to get crappy code working but actually fixing it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most IDEs will show you undefined variables, [PHPStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) does for example. You can let it scan all your source files and you will be notified about undefined variables in all your code, whiteout actually executing it.

This is probably the most simply and painless variant. Alternatively you could obviously write your own script utilizing the [Tokenizer](http://php.net/Tokenizer) and identify all `T_VARIABLE`s, which are not previously initialized using a `T_VARIABLE` `'='` `expr` construct. But this will be more error prone. Using the IDE will probably give you better results with less effort.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about PHPStorm.  I will be giving that a try later today.  I might also take a look at Tokenizer.  That route would probably be overkill for just me, but perhaps I will build something with it, and release it for others to use.

Comment: @Brad: And, did you use PHPStorm? Or have you written something yourself?

Comment: I am waiting on PHPStorm to get back to me about my free educational license.  They have a manual approval process it seems.  Looking over it though, I do believe that will do the job, or at least help significantly.

Comment: @Brad: They have a demo version, which you can use for 45 days I think ;)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming single files are always using register_globals being on or off, you could create a list of all form element names which are submitted to a script and then check this script if it's using `$fieldname` without containing `$_REQUEST['fieldname']` (or the `$_POST`, `$_GET` arrays).

Your "check for notices" method would be ok if you can guarantee a very high code coverage while doing those checks (to ensure you didn't miss anything - the uncovered parts then have to be checked manually).

Comment: Trouble is, I have no way of knowing what is being submitted to a script.  I'm not talking about a few pages here and there, or even contained applications... but 200,000+ web pages and PHP scripts.  A lot of these scripts reference other scripts, and some scripts handle posts from other servers/sites.  Good point about possible code paths.  I was assuming that PHP generated an `E_NOTICE` for this anywhere in the code, but just realized that wouldn't be possible until it executed the code using the reference.

Answer (score 2):

While examining your logs for symptoms of scripts written expecting global vars can be helpful, reading through the code is the only way to really do this. If you wanted to automate this, you would need to build or rely on a PHP interpreter; otherwise you're destined to miss stuff nested inside of conditions, potential evals, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  I was hoping to find a way to rely on PHP.exe, but as you have pointed out, simply executing it will miss items in conditional statements.  It's looking like the manual method may be the way to go, if some PHP IDE can't help me identify them.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to locate usages of **register globals** that are strings in running code. You can create the following script and use the PHP [auto_prepend_file](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file) ini options to prepend it to your existing code.

```
<?php

class revealGlobalsUsage {

    public $globalName;
    public $globalVal;

    public function __construct($name, $val)
    {
        $this->globalName = $name;
        $this->globalVal = $val;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        $backtrace = debug_backtrace();

        // log backtrace here...

        return $this->globalVal;
    }
}

// overwrite globals that have been set from GET and POST requests
foreach ($_REQUEST as $name => $val) {
    // Strings that are cast to integers will fail as there 
    // is no __toString equivalent for integers/bool/float etc.
    if (is_string($val) && !is_numeric($val)) {
        $GLOBALS[$name] = new revealGlobalsUsage($name, $val);
    }

    // You can log all GET/POST requests here...
}
```

For integers etc. you would need to patch your PHP: https://gist.github.com/ircmaxell/1966809

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem myself in an enormous codebase with thousands of files. Inspired by the solution posted by @sschueller I have tested this auto_prepend_file code which logs occurrences for investigation. This method should also be used in conjunction with parsing/tokenizing to catch all occurrences.

```
<?php

$vars = get_defined_vars();

foreach ($vars as $var => $value) {
    if (in_array($var, array('$_SERVER', '$_REQUEST', '$_GET', '$_POST', '$_COOKIE', '$_SESSION', '$_FILES', '$_ENV'))) {
        // only examine the local symbols, not superglobals
        continue;
    }

    if (array_key_exists($var, $_REQUEST) && $value == $_REQUEST[$var]) {
        error_log(sprintf("register_globals reliance detected in %s for variable %s=%s", $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'], $var, $value), 3, "/var/tmp/register_globals.log");
    }
}
```