# PHP & OCI8: How can I identify a true dependency on an Oracle Database?

Tags: php, cron, oracle-call-interface, oci8

I have a number of production cron scripts that have unclear dependencies.  The crons may or may not depend on an Oracle database backend. I need a function call that I can include in a PHP script to determine if *any* query or statement was executed during the execution of the script.

Note that some of the crons may connect to the database without executing any statements at all. Thus, simply using `get_included_files()` or `get_required_files()` (to determine if the script that initializes the connection is included) is not sufficient.

Comment: Open the scripts and check?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, what if I'm in "b.php" and include "a.php" which includes another library that executes a query. Performing a `grep` in "b.php" for, say, `oci_execute()` is not sufficient. This is a *very large*, legacy code base, so I need an automated solution.

Answer (score 0):

The first things that comes to mind is to use [Oracle auditing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dsl/php-web-auditing-171451.html) and the second is to write a wrapper around `oci_execute()` and do some logging in the application.

Comment: The link looks quite useful. I'll check it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's no great automatic way to do this.  You can't simply log for when your database is used, since you say you have a "very large, legacy code base".  How would you know when you reached all of the code paths?

You'll have to apply a human approach.  Look at the places that do call database functions, start disconnecting things, use some intuition about where to look next.  In the end, disconnect and see what breaks... but have a plan for knowing where to look for broken things, based on your inspection of the code.

I had a similar problem awhile back, but with `register_globals` instead of database dependencies.  You might find this question and its answers helpful:  [Finding PHP scripts that require register_globals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4890229/finding-php-scripts-that-require-register-globals)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My idea was to use `register_shutdown_function()` with the `auto_prepend_file` setting to log when the database was used.  That solves the logging issue.  The question is how to determine if the database was used at all.

Comment: By the way, I acknowledge that my proposed method may only provide a 90% solution.  I'm okay with that. It would still save my team *a lot* of time.